# To get a huxtable in 2 pages in PDF type RMD

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, gt

I have a `huxtable` to be printed which is at the end of the first page. Due to its size and width, the huxtable gets printed on the second page. Is there any possible way where I can split the portion of the table and project the first half of the table on the first page and the bottom half in the second? I tried the `longtable` and other tex methods. Also, I don't want `kable` package to be used since it reduces the aesthetics of the table.
A sample Huxtable demo as a solution would help me a lot and would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but it appears `huxtable` does not support automatic pagination. You could try splitting the table - search for `Splitting tables` on [this page](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html). Or even do this manually by printing select rows.

In the past I have successfully produced tables spanning multiple pages, but I only used `longtable` and not `huxtable`.

Comment: Thanks, Micheal, so even if split works, how can I make it print in 2 different pages?

Comment: You do `hux_list <- split_across(ht, after = 5)` which gives you a list of huxtables. Then you print them as normal like `hux_list[[1]]`, `hux_list[[2]]`. To explicitly change pages you could use e.g. `\newpage` within your TeX or Rmarkdown. Alternatively you can rely on TeX's positioning algorithm to print them for you, see `?latex_float`.